# Python : for-loop not looping in correctly

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to write the contents of an extract to a spreadsheet by using a for loop.

Given below is the content on which I am trying to perform the loop:

```
fruit1
apple
fruit2
banana
fruit3
pears
```

Expected Output:

```
fruit1,fruit2,fruit3
apple,banana,pears
```

I am trying to perform a loop as below:

```
row = 0
col = 0
row1 = 1
col1 = 0


for elem in tree.iter():
    worksheet1.write(row, col, elem.tag)
    for subelem in elem:
        worksheet1.write(row1, col1, subelem.text)
    col +=1
```

Current output:

```
fruit1,fruit2,fruit3
```

I see the value that need to be updated in the column header (elem.tag) have got copied but the corresponding row value (subelem.text) does not get copied.

Could anyone assist on how could I fix this. Thanks

Comment: What is your ``tree`` variable?

Comment: @DocDriven, I am using tree.iter()  to fetch values from a xml file.